# SQL Select statement to present data multidimentional

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g, pivot

I'm Working on a complex SQL Statement to present data in many dimensions,

```
---------------------------------
YEAR  |  MONTH   | ARTICLVALUE  |
---------------------------------
2013       01        45665
2013       02        2364
2013       03        98736
2013       04        6623541
2013       05        9856
2012       02        23102
2012       06        10002
2012       07        120
```

I woul like to present this like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------
YEAR       |  MONTH1  |  MONTH2  |  MONTH3  |.......
---------------------------------------------------
    2013       45665      2364       98736
```

Is it possible using SQL Statement?

Comment: Column `MONTH` is also requirement?

Comment: Sorry, it not requirement, it was my fault and i correct it. thanks

Comment: what version of oracle have you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIVOT` is not available in 10g yet (it appeared only in 11g and works as displayed in techdo's answer), so you have to work this around. Here's one possible way:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8feef/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
    ("Y" int, "M" int, "V" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2013, 01, 45665)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2013, 02, 2364)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2013, 03, 98736)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2013, 04, 6623541)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2013, 05, 9856)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2012, 02, 23102)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2012, 06, 10002)
    INTO DATA ("Y", "M", "V")
         VALUES (2012, 07, 120)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
y 
,max(m1) m1
,max(m2) m2
,max(m3) m3
,max(m4) m4
,max(m5) m5
,max(m6) m6
,max(m7) m7
,max(m8) m8
,max(m9) m9
,max(m10) m10
,max(m11) m11
,max(m12) m12
from (
  select 
   y
  ,decode(m, 1, v) m1
  ,decode(m, 2, v) m2
  ,decode(m, 3, v) m3
  ,decode(m, 4, v) m4
  ,decode(m, 5, v) m5
  ,decode(m, 6, v) m6
  ,decode(m, 7, v) m7
  ,decode(m, 8, v) m8 
  ,decode(m, 9, v) m9
  ,decode(m, 10, v) m10
  ,decode(m, 11, v) m11
  ,decode(m, 12, v) m12
  from data
) t
group by y
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8feef/2/0)**:

```
|    Y |     M1 |    M2 |     M3 |      M4 |     M5 |     M6 |     M7 |     M8 |     M9 |    M10 |    M11 |    M12 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013 |  45665 |  2364 |  98736 | 6623541 |   9856 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 2012 | (null) | 23102 | (null) |  (null) | (null) |  10002 |    120 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```